# Using pandas/matplotlib/python, I cannot visualize my csv file as clusters

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

My csv file is, 
https://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/master/challenge2/data/total_watt.csv

I want to visualize this csv file as clusters.
My ideal result would be the following image.(Higher points (red zone) would be higher energy consumption and lower points (blue zone) would be lower energy consumption.)

I want to set x-axis as dates (e.g. 2011-04-18), y-axis as time (e.g. 13:22:00), and z-axis as energy consumption (e.g. 925.840613752523).

[image]

I successfully visualized the csv data file as values per 30mins with the following program.

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

filename='total_watt.csv'
date=[]
number=[]

import csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        if len(row) ==2 :
            date.append(row[0])
            number.append(row[1])

number=np.array(number)

import datetime
for ii in range(len(date)):
    date[ii]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[ii], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.plot(date,number)

plt.title('Example')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I also succeeded to visualize the csv data file as values per day with the following program.

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

style.use('ggplot')

filename='total_watt.csv'
date=[]
number=[]

import csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:

    df = pd.read_csv('total_watt.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
    df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')





import datetime
for ii in range(len(date)):
    date[ii]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[ii], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.plot(date,number)

plt.title('Example')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Although I could visualize the csv file as values per 30mins and per days, I do not have any idea to visualize the csv data as clusters in 3D..

How can I program it...?

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you are wanting from that image, anyway you could explain a bit better? My thinking right now is that you want to separate the date and time and use the date as x-axis and time as y-axis, then use the data for your z-axis. Also note, that you don't have to open the csv file before you do a ```pd.read_csv()```. I am not at my home computer currently, but I may be able to when I make it home.

Comment: Thank you for ur comment, NightHallow.

Comment: Thank you for ur comment, NightHallow!  I want to visualize energy data in 3D graph with colors which is red when energy consumption is high and is blue when the consumption is low.

Comment: and sorry, it is difficult to explain what I want..lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is probably just reshaping your data so that you have date along one dimension and time along the other.  Once you do that you can use whatever plotting you like best (here I've used matplotlib's mplot3d, but it has some quirks).

What follows takes your data and reshapes it appropriately so you can then plot a surface that I believe is what your are looking for.  The key is using the `pivot` method, which restructures your data by date and time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fname = 'total_watt.csv'

# Read in the data, but I skipped setting the index and made sure no data
# is lost to a nonexistent header
df = pd.read_csv(fname, parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['datetime', 'watt'])

# We want to separate the date from the time, so create two new columns
df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [x.time() for x in df['datetime']]

# Now we want to reshape the data so we have dates and times making the result 2D
pv = df.pivot(index='time', columns='date', values='watt')

# Not every date has every time, so fill in the subsequent NaNs or there will be holes
# in the surface
pv = pv.fillna(0.0)

# Now, we need to construct some arrays that matplotlib will like for X and Y values
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:len(pv),0:len(pv.columns)]

# We can now plot the values directly in matplotlib using mplot3d
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, pv.values, cmap='jet', rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.grid(False)

# Now we have to adjust the ticks and ticklabels - so turn the values into strings
dates = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in pv.columns]
times = [str(x) for x in pv.index]

# Setting a tick every fifth element seemed about right
ax.set_xticks(xx[::5,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(times[::5])
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::5])
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::5])

plt.show()
```

This gives me (using your data) the following graph:

[image: 3D surface plot of clustered data]

Note that I've assumed when plotting and making the ticks that your dates and times are linear (which they are in this case).  If you have data with uneven samples, you'll have to do some interpolation before plotting.

Comment: I would also suggest checking out [Mayavi, specifically mlab](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) for the 3D plotting. Can be easier and typically you can do a bit more with it (it's definitely not for every project, just nice to know it exist)

Comment: Thank you. I will chek this out!! :)))

Comment: How you set time to x-axis!?!?! your code is "times = [str(x) for x in pv.index]" though..

Comment: And I could understand your code, except 
ax.set_xticks(xx[::5,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(times[::5])
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::5])
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::5])
What does this "[::5]" mean!?!??!?

Comment: Egad, be calm.  `[::5]` is extremely standard Python indexing (it's a step, it means take every fifth element).  If you don't know that, you should brush up on your basic Python.  And in this code the axes themselves are just integers, all I did was change the tick *labels* (strings) to match the appropriate time/date.  If you want to swap the time and date (i.e. make date on x and time on y) ... just swap them wherever they appear.